# Want to slideup fixed area with jQuery and CSS

Tags: jquery, css, slideup

I'd like to implement a function as `slideUp` of [Magic](https://www.minimamente.com/example/magic_animations/).
I wrote a code following this, and here is [my sample page](https://bananaman.herokuapp.com/slideup_like_magic/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning jQuery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
        div#foo {
            height: 100px;
            background-color: red;
        }
        div#bar {
            height: 100px;
            background-color: green;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="foo">Apple Orange</div>
    <div id="bar">Banana Lemon</div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>HTML</li>
            <li>CSS</li>
            <li>JavaScript</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("div#foo").animate(
                    {height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow", function() {
                        $("div#bar").show();
                });
            }, 2000);
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

It seems it works, but `<ul>` area also moves.
I don't want `<ul>` area to move and want only `<div>` area to move and be changed.
How should I write code?
Would you please help me?

Add: What I want to implement is `<div id="foo">` slidesUp and even while `<div id="foo">` is slidingUp, we can see `<div id="bar">` under `<div id="foo">`.

Comment: First of all, don't use js and css within a one html file. Write it in a three separate files. Then provide us a jsfiddle link.

Comment: From what I understood, you want div foo to shrink in height but you don't want bar to move, right?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, K Daniek and Naveen Attri. I changed css and might solve this, though I do not know if that is proper... I used `z-index`.

Comment: @K.Daniek Thank you for your advice. Yeah, I usually do like what you wrote, but it was test, so I wrote all in a html file. Sorry.

Comment: @NaveenAttri Yes, what I wanted to implement is like turning papers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this:

```
   ul{
       position: absolute;
       z-index: 5;
       margin-top: 22px;
     }
```

Comment: Thank you for your advaice, sTx.